# Can you sync a dual boot Linux system and with a windows virtual machine?

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, multi-boot

I have a laptop setup with dual boot enabled so that I have the choice to choose windows or Linux on startup. I also have virtual box installed on both OS’s. I know this is sort of a lazy question, but I wanted to minimize the disruption to my workflow with easier access to the alternative OS (I.e. I don’t want to have to reboot to switch OS’s for something small). So ideally the Linux VM and Linux (dual boot) OS would reference the same files, drive, etc. so that any changes to one would therefore apply to / appear on both? (So If I add a file in the “dual boot” linux OS, it will show up in the linux VM as well, and vice versa) I assume all I need is to make the Linux vm share the same disk space and root directory as the dual boot, but when it comes to Linux / virtual box I’m am not a super user, more of a standard user, so I’m not sure how to set it up.

Hardware setup (if needed) [I have 16 gb RAM & 1.5 terabytes ssd (1:1 tb drive; 1:500gb drive), so I could give each their own physical disk and I can upgrade to 2 tb (1 tb on each disk) if I need the space, didn’t think that would be an issue]

Comment: Could you please reformat your question so it is easier to read? Right now it's just one big block of text and it's hard to tell what your goal is.

Answer (score 0):

Use a thumb drive or a shared directory / partition on the windows side for your code shared with your VM and duplicate that share on the Linux VM.

Linux can access (R,W,X) everything in the Windows partition / drive via the ntfs-3g package but Windows cannot see or access anything on the Linux side so that is why you set up the initial share on the windows side or a ntfs / fat external drive and then access the same data from the Linux side.